# Artboard Style Layout Using CSS Transform Scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

I'd like to have the .container and .box scale in and out from the one I clicked on. The problem I'm running into is when I scale in and out, it scales in and out from the first .box div, not the one I clicked on.

Each .box will contain it's own unique content, so when viewing this in "Artboard" view (Zoomed Out), I want people to be able to see what's contained in that particular .box. When people click on one of the boxes, I want it to scale back to (1) to cover the viewport. And if the person is on the 4th .box and they click "Zoom Out", I want it to zoom out from that particular .box.

Each box will be the size of the viewport, which is how it's set up now.

Does anyone have a solution in CSS only? Or is this something that can be better accomplished in JS? I'm not a JS expert, I'm just getting into it, so I'm curious if there's something I can do in some simple JS.

Please see my codepen:

http://codepen.io/jareko999/pen/eZGLZB

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
  <button class="zoomout" onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button> 
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="artboard">  
    <div class="box">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  padding: 14px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.zoomout {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.container-small {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(.7);
}

.artboard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.box {
  padding-top: 44vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #a9a9a9;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #276cd6 , #00a651);
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.box-small {
  padding-top: 44vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #a9a9a9;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #276cd6 , #00a651);
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  transform: scale(.9);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box i {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.remove {
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  height: 4px;
}

/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #4099ff; 
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.container').addClass('overflow');
});

function zoomOut() {
  $('.bar').addClass('remove');
  $('.box').addClass('box-small');
  $('.container').removeClass('overflow');
  $('.container').addClass('container-small');
}

$('.box').click(function() {
  $('.bar').removeClass('remove');
  $('.box').removeClass('box-small');
  $('.container').addClass('overflow');
  $('.container').removeClass('container-small');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done using a CSS only method.
This method relies on using location hashes (url.com#foobar) and the `:target` pseudo selector.

The `:target` pseudo selector allows you to target the element which has the id matching the location hash. For example, imagine you have an element with the id "foobar", the `#foobar:target` selector will only apply if you have navigated to `url.com#foobar`. You can create a link with the href attribute pointing `#foobar` to have a button trigger this pseudo selector.

In your case, you can apply the zoom out styles when the #container location hash is matched, and only show the slide matched by the location hash.

The drawback of this method is that you have to add ids, and add links to actually trigger the `:target` pseudo class.

My explanation might not be clear, so I put up this demo:
http://codepen.io/ntim/pen/ONxGJd

Comment: Thanks Tim! That definitely helps.